# color of list items is not changing

Tags: javascript

I was trying to change the background color and the text using JS
the background color and the text of the body changed
but the text color of the list items in my nav bar didn't change. Why is this happening?

Code:

```js
const dark = document.querySelector('.dark')
dark.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && dark.value === 'dark') {
    document.body.style.background = '#151515'
    const textColor = document.querySelectorAll("body").forEach(function(e) {
      e.style.color = '#fff'
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<header class="hero">
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="collection">
      <li class="items"><a href="" class="nav-link">home</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="" class="nav-link">work</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="" class="nav-link">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="terminal">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="btn red"></div>
    <div class="btn yellow"></div>
    <div class="btn green"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="dollar">$ type help for more</span> <br>
  <span class="pound">$ </span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="" class="dark"><br>
  <span class="pound">$ </span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="help" class="help">
</div>
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll("body") here you need li rather than body

Comment: So then there must be a definition of `color` on either the list items or any of their non-body-ancestors. Why not just check in the devtools where the color comes from?

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't return anything useful, why are you assigning the result to the `textColor` variable (which you also never use)?

Comment: The list items are still inheriting the default color.

Comment: Why do you need to use `forEach()` with the `body` selector? There can only be one `<body>` element.

Comment: Since the `<li>` contains `<a>`, the browser's default style for links overrides the color that's inherited from `body`.

Comment: @deepak 
I want the color of the body and all the text within it change black. the color of the text is changing  except the "li"

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes they are

Comment: I realised my comment wasn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
const dark = document.querySelector('.dark')
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link')
dark.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
if (e.keyCode === 13 && dark.value === 'dark') {
   document.body.style.background = '#151515'
   document.querySelector("body").style.color = '#fff'
   list.forEach(el => {
    el.style.color = '#fff'
})
}
})
```

Comment: yes this is helpful and it solved the problem I didn't noticed that a tag was the child of li
thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are applying color to `body` but `<a>` tags have their own browser default color. You also don't need `forEach` for `body`, you need it for `list`. Change your Js to this:

```js
const dark = document.querySelector('.dark')
dark.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  if(e.keyCode===13 && dark.value === 'dark'){
    document.body.style.background = '#151515'
    document.querySelector("body").style.color = '#fff'
    document.querySelectorAll(".collection li a").forEach(function(e){
        e.style.color = '#fff'
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<body>


<header class="hero">
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="collection">
        <li class="items"><a href="" class="nav-link">home</a></li>
        <li class="items"><a href="" class="nav-link">work</a></li>
        <li class="items"><a href="" class="nav-link">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
<div class="terminal">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="btn red"></div>
    <div class="btn yellow"></div>
    <div class="btn green"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="dollar">$ type help for more</span> <br>
  <span class="pound">$ </span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="" class="dark"><br>
  <span class="pound">$ </span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="help" class="help">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! I forgot about the a tag and didn't notice that it was the child of li
I was appling querySelectorAll() thinking that it will also select the child elements of it.